# Value outside function doesn`t match inside function, C

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure, push

Please, I got a problem and I need help.

Got struct (stack):

```
struct sAddress {
    tBSTNodePtr *data;
    struct sAddress *pointer_next;
}*ads_stack;
```

then I have PUSH function

```
void pushAds(tBSTNodePtr hodnota)
{
    struct sAddress *temp;
    temp = (struct sAddress*)malloc(sizeof(struct sAddress));
    temp->data = &hodnota;
    if (ads_stack == NULL) {
        ads_stack = temp;
        ads_stack->pointer_next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        temp->pointer_next = ads_stack;
        ads_stack = temp;
    }
    printf("PUSH ADS KEY: %s\n", ads_stack->data->Key->str);
}
```

When I push something (in `tBSTNodePtr` ofcourse) it will print value of `Key->str` properly. But when I try to printf the same outside the function like this:

```
printf("STACK DATA: %s\n", ads_stack->data->Key->str);
```

It will give me segfault (tried on Win 8.1 under codeblocks, and under Fedora using makefile). What I do wrong? Are pointers wrong? `ads_stack` is not NULL outside push function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that

```
temp->data = &hodnota;
```

is refering to the address of the local variable hodnota (which is a param received).

could you explain what tBSTNodePtr is?

`temp->data` is a `tBSTNodePtr *`, and in your function you receive a `tBSTNodePtr`, not a `tBSTNodePtr *`. if you use `&hodnota` you will be referencing the address of the local parameter, when you leave your function it is out of scope, that variable doesn't exist anymore.

You should:

- Pass a pointer to `tBSTNodePtr`
- create a copy of `hodnota` inside your function

But maybe it all depends on what `tBSTNodePtr` is if it is a pointer to a BSTNode, then probably you should change other things. Probably changing the struct removing the `*` in data and changing `temp->data = &hodnota;` to `temp->data = hodnota;`

As a side note:

```
temp = (struct sAddress*)malloc(sizeof(struct sAddress));
```

The cast to `struct sAddress *` isn't mandatory in C. You can avoid it. Maybe something like:

```
temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

looks better.

Comment: Yay! Used this and with combination of `pushAds(tBSTNodePtr *hodnota)` working like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

replace `void pushAds(tBSTNodePtr hodnota)`  by void `pushAds(tBSTNodePtr *hodnota)`
if you want to use `hodnota struct` to read parameter in your main function

but if you want to change `hodnota struct` you have to use void `pushAds(tBSTNodePtr **hodnota)`
and then replace `temp->data = &hodnota;` by `temp->data = *hodnota;`